# Why does Java outputs decimal number as Integer?

Tags: java

So here is my program:

```
// Creates a Scanner object that monitors keyboard input
static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.print("How old are you? ");

    int age = checkValidAge();

    if (age != 0)
    {
    System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old");
    }

}

public static int checkValidAge() 
{

    try
    {
        return userInput.nextInt(); // nextInt() receives the user input
    }

    catch (InputMismatchException e)
    {
        userInput.next(); // Skips the last user input and waits for the next
        System.out.print("That isn't a whole number");
        return 0;
    }

}
```

When I enter a number with 3 decimal places, Java outputs it as an Integer:

[image]

If I input the number with 2 or more than 3 decimal points, then the program will know that input is not correct. So why does it ignore 3 decimal places and outputs it as an int?

Comment: Please show the output as text, not as screenshot. Also please include at least one "working" and one "not working" sample and what that "not working" sample is *supposed* to look like.

Comment: `userInput.nextInt(); // nextInt() receives the user input` no it doesn't. It receives the next int, which it will stop parsing when it encounters a dot (or other decimal separator). Your code isn't rounding what it parses, instead it is truncating it by avoiding to parse the decimal part. Just use `.nextDouble` instead

Comment: Because those are not decimal places, `,` is the thousand separator in your situation.

Comment: Wether or not Java interprets a comma or a point as a decimal mark or simply a thousand separator depends on the Locale of your computer/JVM. obiously you are running the prgramm in an environment where comma is considered a thousand seperator.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn’t have a decimal points in it! It has a comma, which is a thousands separator in your locale, but no point. Programming is about describing things precisely. There is no problem with your input since “2,444” is a valid integer.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Even if I use the dot, the ouput will stil be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stream::nextInt` reads an integer from a stream.
`2,444` is an integer in your default locale (`2,444 = 2444`).

If you want to read a decimal number you need to use the `Stream::nextDouble` or another appropriate method.

Comment: If I input 2,22 for example, it will say that the input number is not a whole number. But if I input 2,222 for example, it will say that the inputted number is 2222. It only outputs the integer if there are exactly three places after comma. Why?

Comment: Because only groups of three digits to the right of the comma are actually a valid number. 2,222 is an integer. 2,222,222 is an integer. 2,22 is not.

Comment: No, this is just a notation that differers based on locale. Not specific to Java. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping